# Get the latest comment from a custom post type where depth = 1?

Tags: custom-post-types, comments

Happy new year everyone.

I've been struggling with this one for a while.
I need to get the latest comment from a custom post type, but ignore any child comments i.e. only look at comments with a depth of 1.

I can get the latest comment from a custom post type using:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom-post-type',
    'number' => '1',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
  );

$comments = get_comments($args);
foreach($comments as $comment) :
    echo($comment->comment_author . '<br />' . $comment->comment_content);
endforeach;
```

However, it doesn't take into account the depth requirement.  Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the "parent" parameter as 0.

```
$args = array(
    'parent' => 0,    
    'post_type' => 'custom-post-type',
    'number' => '1',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
  );

$comments = get_comments($args);
foreach($comments as $comment) :
    echo($comment->comment_author . '<br />' . $comment->comment_content);
endforeach;
```